# Issue with Cron Job - Newbie!

Tags: centos, cron

I have created a script and can execute it from command line with no issues works perfectly. I have now tried to set it up as a 15 minute recurring cron job and it seems to run something as the file is created in the correct place however it is empty.

this is my cron job line

```
 */2 * * * * root /root/cron.database-backup.sh
```

and I am editing /etc/crontab

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you editing `/etc/crontab` directly via an editor or using `crontab -e`? You **should** be using `crontab -e`.

Comment: i have been using nano /etc/crontab, it seems that the script is getting run but for some reason the script is not working fully while the same script works fine run directly from the command line

Comment: actually your correct, can you post it as an answer and i will mark it as correct for you.

Comment: You have to say @pacey to make sure to get the attention of the user you're talking to unless the comment is attached to their question or answer (like this one is to yours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a file that cron uses that lists all the cron jobs.

You shouldn't edit this file directly, but you should use the crontab 
command to edit it.

So:

```
crontab [-u user] -l        ### will list the current cron jobs
crontab [-u user] -e        ### will drop you into an editor to edit the jobs
```

the -u user part is optional, and should only be used if you want to edit 
the crontab file for a user you are not logged in as.